# How to store a "secret" string in a Windows Store App Package

Tags: security, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winjs

As you probably know, it's incredibly easy to dig into the source code of a Windows Store App, made with HTML, CSS and JS.

My app uses a REST API which starts a quite expensive operation on a server. To save CPU resources the API uses something like an HMAC. To generate the HMAC, a secret is needed. How can I securely save that secret? I'm searching for something like the iOS keystore.

Comment: Who are you trying to prevent starting the expensive operation? Do you have authentication for the application functionality? If store anything as part of the app package, it won't be fully secure, and even less so if you're using HTTP/S.

Comment: It's about preventing abusive usage of the service, it's already in place and proved and tested. I also don't expect "full security" as this probably does not exist. When calling the Webservice we auth the app not the user. So there are no user passwords.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As everything in the code could be analyzed, decompiled, debugged, eventually, it seems like an effort of obfuscation rather than security if you want to release the application with a key embedded as part of your application package.

Since you don't use user security to control access, instead, I'd suggest you consider a scheme which you would activate and authorize the application rather than trying to store a "secret" somewhere within the application.

If you added a RESTful API for application authorization, you could:

1. Track application activations by device
2. Provide a unique activation code to each device (a token)
3. Monitor, per device, usage of the APIs, including the service that starts the expensive operation.

To get a unique hardware ID for your application, you'd need to read this guide: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553431.aspx

Once you've got the token, you could use the `PasswordVault` to store the token securely:

```
var vault = new Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault();
vault.add(new Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordCredential(
    "MyWindows8App", "default", token));
```

[PasswordVault documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.credentials.passwordvault.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`PasswordVault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.credentials.passwordvault.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=javascript#code-snippet-1) to store sensitive data. [Here's MSDN sample.](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Credential-locker-sample-8e3278af)

You can also use [local storage setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.Aspx), which is also not accessible.

Comment: How would that help? Neither store data in the app package.